# Create WiX EventSource for .NET 4.5

Tags: .net, wix, event-log

I'm upgrading an application from .NET 4.0 to .NET 4.5.

Previously in my installer, I had this:

```
<u:EventSource Name="$(var.MainExe)" Log="Application" EventMessageFile="[NETFRAMEWORK40FULLINSTALLROOTDIR]EventLogMessages.dll" />
```

However, looking at [the documentation](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/wixnetfxextension.html), there doesn't seem to be an equivalent to `NETFRAMEWORK40FULLINSTALLROOTDIR` for .NET 4.5.

How should I be updating this line of installer for .NET 4.5? Is there an undocumented variable, or is there now a whole different way of working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET 4.5 (and 4.5.1 and 4.5.2 and 4.6) are in-place upgrades for .NET 4.0, so you can use the same property.

Comment: Does that work? That's very ugly, that I use a varaible named NETFRAMEWORK40* to refer to something for 4.5! Oh well, thank you.